# Combining two arrays of objects using Object.assign()?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am not quite sure why Object.assign() is not providing the expected result (see the commented out section at the bottom). Am I missing something with the function, or is there a cleaner way to do this?

The code below reaches the for loop with the variable "i" but does not reach the second for loop with the variable "x".

```js
    const array_1 = [{property1:'a',property2:'b'}, {property1:'c',property2:'d'}];
const array_2 = [{property3:'w',property4:'x'}, {property3:'y',property4:'z'}];

const CombineArrays = (array_1, array_2) => {
  let combined_array = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < array_1.length; i++) {
    for (let x = 0; x < array_2.length; x++) {
      const newObj = Object.assign(array_1[i], array_2[x]);
      combined_array.push(newObj);
    }
  }
  return combined_array;
};

const result = CombineArrays(array_1, array_2);
console.log(result);


// expected result = [
//     {property1:'a',property2:'b', property3:'w',property4:'x'},
//     {property1:'a',property2:'b', property3:'y',property4:'z'},
//     {property1:'c',property2:'d', property3:'w',property4:'x'},
//     {property1:'c',property2:'d', property3:'y',property4:'z'}
// ]
// current result = [
//     { property1: 'a', property2: 'b', property3: 'y', property4: 'z' },
//     { property1: 'a', property2: 'b', property3: 'y', property4: 'z' },
//     { property1: 'c', property2: 'd', property3: 'y', property4: 'z' },
//     { property1: 'c', property2: 'd', property3: 'y', property4: 'z' }
// ]
```

Comment: There is a failure within the second for loop: `for (let x = 0; x < array_2.length; x++) {`. The `length` property is missing. The other problem is that you modify the the elements of the `array_1`, instead you should make a copy and assign new properties: `Object.assign({}, array_1[i], array_2[x]);`

Comment: @iY1NQ Thanks so much for noting that; super helpful. But now the output still isn't what I expected. See the updated code and code-comment at the bottom. Specifically, it isn't outputting array_2[1]

Comment: @MarkBaijens I updated the typo and it still didn't produce the expected output.

Comment: Your code is still missing `Object.assign({}, array_1[i], array_2[x])`.  Without copying  to an empty object first, you are always overwriting the elements of `array_1`.

Comment: @iY1NQ ah! Sorry, you did say that the first time, I was just overexcited by the missing .length. This fixes everything. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can merge objects with the `...` spread operator. Then you get your desired result because you are not overwriting the original array.

```js
const array_1 = [{property1:'a',property2:'b'}, {property1:'c',property2:'d'}];
const array_2 = [{property3:'w',property4:'x'}, {property3:'y',property4:'z'}];

const CombineArrays = (array_1, array_2) => {
  let combined_array = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < array_1.length; i++) {
    for (let x = 0; x < array_2.length; x++) {
      const newObj = {...array_1[i], ...array_2[x]};
      combined_array.push(newObj);
    }
  }
  return combined_array;
};

const result = CombineArrays(array_1, array_2);
console.log(result);
```